# Рассылка xls/pdf в MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, xls, xlsx

Друзья, помогите решить задачу.

Необходимо с помощью job'а и sp_send_dbmail отправлять рассылку клиентам с указанием заказа. НО, он может быть настолько большим и емким, что письмо будет километровым).
Поэтому требуется sql query данные сохранять в xls/xlsx (а в идеале pdf) приаттачивать их к письму и отправлять.
Но вот незадача, нет ни одного нормального способа сохранять данные в эти форматы.

Подскажите как лучше решить задачу. Может есть какие-то решения сторонние (ssrs/ssis и вообще все остальное), консольные приложения, cmd команды, я не знаю, что-то еще, t-sql, в общем нужно решение, гугл не помог считай, только костыли..

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну что, неужели никто подобным не занимался ?

Comment: Как я понял, ваша задача - сохранить данные в файл. Самое простое: сохранять их в csv - это можно сделать с помощью t-sql, без привлечения чего-либо стороннего. Если нужен pdf или xls/xlsx, то это можно сделать с помощью SSRS.

Comment: Да делаем выборку и сохраняем. Причем если сохранять в xls, то через insert into OPENROWSE, то нужно сначала создать сам файл с помощью xp_cmdshell, так как эта конструкция не позволяет при сохранении создавать файл, если его нет. BCP умеет, но он более медленны и с кодировками там проблемы. Так вот После этого необходимо найти какое-либо консольное приложение и чере все тоже xp_cmdshell + это приложение конвертить в pdf.

Comment: Гемор выходит, неужели в 21 веке нет специальных решений для этого ??

Comment: вам же написали про SSRS, отчетность в почту по расписанию - как раз одна из его задач

Comment: надо покопать по этому поводу что-то, спасибо.